# Why CURL doesn't get the HTML of page?

Tags: php, html, facebook, curl

Here is my code:

```
<?php

$url = "https://www.facebook.com/login/identify?ctx=recover&lwv=110";
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Host: graph.facebook.com'));
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

var_dump($output);
```

I'm trying to get the content *(html)* of one of facebook's pages. But my code returns a blank page. I mean it returns nothing. Output:

```
bool(false)
```

What's wrong? And how can I fix it?

**Note:** CURL is enable on my php.

Comment: Silly question, have you tried [debugging](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php)? I mean, it seems to me that its logical to do this before asking questions.

Comment: @Xorifelse I'm trying debugging for 1 week ..!

Comment: @Xorifelse Also this is the result the link you provided `Curl error: Failed to connect to www.facebook.com port 443: Connection refused`

Comment: @MartinAJ try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);` and removing `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);`

Comment: @PraveenKumar I did it, but sadly nothing changes .. thank you anyway

Comment: try this to debug and let me know `$results = curl_exec($ch);$info = curl_getinfo($ch);echo "<pre>";print_r($info);echo "</pre>"; echo "<pre>";echo curl_errno($ch); echo "</pre>"; echo "<pre>";echo curl_error($ch); echo "</pre>";die();curl_close($ch);`

Comment: Facebook doesn’t permit using any such automated logins anyway. If you want to interact with Facebook - use their API.

Answer (score 0):

It is **not good** to run automated script against facebook. You better use their graph api if you need anything form them.

Right now you are not getting anything as you are not handling redirect, and also not providing any user-agent string.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('User-Agent: Opera 11'));
```

Comment: sometimes you have no choice. like in this project https://github.com/divinity76/msgme , because Facebook does not have an API for sending messages